# Animate changing the image of a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios

There was another post with this question but none of the solutions worked.  My problem is that I have a couple of imageViews that I need to change the images of.  It seems weird if I abruptly change them so I was wondering whether there was a way to fade the new image in.

This is when I set one of the imageViews.

```
self.imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [images objectAtIndex:newArray[0]]]];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fading in an imageView can be achieved in multiple ways.  If you could post your code, (how do you change the view without fading-in now) others will be able to suggest easiest approach

Edit: Try animating the alpha like in the code below:

```
self.imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [images objectAtIndex:newArray[0]]]];
self.imgView1.alpha=0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                    self.imgView1.alpha=1;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```

You can control the values of animateWithDuration and delay to suit your app

Let us know if it works